# Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed

Tags: actionscript

I have a .swf file which throws this error when I attempt to load it in a browser.  Similar to other posts here this is the code:

```
var mySpite:Sprite = new Sprite();
var button:Loader = new Loader();
var url:String = "images/btnImage.png";
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
button.load(urlReq);
....
```

When I run the actionscript in Flex Build it works fine.  Also when I double click the .swf file in the folder where it is stored, it works fine.  I don't know why it only doesn't work and throws this error when I load it in a .jsp page.

Comment: It's probably an issue with your path. Remember the path to the image will be relative to the page which embeds the SWF.

Comment: Ahhh now it works. Ugh, sucks though now I have to keep changing the url path to develop and deploy.  net.uk.sweet you should post that as an answer to the question so I can accept it.

Comment: Will do. Getting pretty close to 3k ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely an issue with your path. Remember that the path to the image will be relative to the page which embeds the SWF.

In answer to your comment about having to change the paths when deploying, depending on how you're building and debugging your SWF, it might be possible to use `Capabilities.playerType` (see [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html)) to choose the correct path for the current environment. Another alternative might be to put all your image references in a couple of XML files (one local and one remote). As long as the path to the XML file is consistent between local and remote environments, you can update the SWF without worrying about the image paths.